# ios Build works only 24 hours

Tags: ios, build

I'm making an ad-hoc build with a valid certificate and provisioning profile.
Both are expiring in 2018. However, this build is valid only for 24 hours.
After that, the app is not opening.
Please help me, what can be the reason?

Comment: What exactly happens "that app is not opening"? What makes you think it's caused by the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to "the app is not opening" as in, it's not opening on your iPhone after 24 hours, than that is completely normal. In order to run it on your iPhone after that you need to reconnect your phone to your computer and run the app on it.

In order to get that to stop I believe you have to enrol in the Apple Developer Program.

Answer (score 0):

Found what was an issue. So on one account was two iOS developers. And when I was creating distribution certificate, I didn't send other developer Private key for it. In this case he just reseted my certificate and created his own.
That's caused such strange things. I just didn't know that someone else are reseting it...